# _ZdlPvj procedure entry point not found in DLL <path>Exe.exe .How do i fix it?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, gnu-make

It occurs every time i compile 2 cpp files in one of which i try to initialize a pointer of TMap or GameObject class. Im new to c++ and i am using SDL2.

I tried to make it static in Game class, this error also occured.

```cpp
SDL_Renderer* Game::renderer = nullptr;
SDL_Window* Game::window = nullptr;
GameObject* Player = nullptr;///this doesnt create error
TMap* Map = nullptr;///this also doesnt create error
void Game::init(int w, int h, bool fullscreen)
{
    Uint32 flag = 0;
    if(fullscreen)
    {
        flag = SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;
    }
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)==0)
    {
        Game::window = SDL_CreateWindow("A game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, w, h, flag);
        Game::renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(Game::window, -1, 0);
        std::cout << "Game Initialised" << std::endl;
        isrunning = true;
        Player = new GameObject("assets/aliendisplay.png", 0 ,0);/////this creates error
        Map = new Map("assets/lowtileset.png");///this also creates error
    }
    else
    {
        isrunning = false;
    }
}
```

```
build : Main.cpp SecondCpp.cpp header.h 
g++ Main.cpp SecondCpp.cpp -I. -IPATH\include\SDL2 -IPATH\SDL2_image\include\SDL2 -LPATH\SDL2\lib -LPATH\SDL2_image\lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -o Exe
```

When running makefile, there are no errors.

Comment: It would be helpful to see your makefle and how you link against SDL. Provide a [mcve] as required here please.

Comment: Add additional information into your question please, not in comments.

Comment: Recommend using `'/'` as the directory separator (windows will respect it), or change to `"\\"`. g++ is likely interpreting `\X` as a single escaped character.